# The ViewData item that has the key 'CityId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 `       public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        property property = db.Properties.Find(id);

        try
        {
            ViewBag.City = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "City", property.CityId);
            ViewBag.Locality_Id = new SelectList(db.Areas, "Locality_Id", "Locality", property.Locality_Id);
            ViewBag.citylist = _data.getCity();
            ViewBag.typeproperty = _data.TypeProperty();
            ViewBag.Rooms = _data.RoomDetails();
            ViewBag.bath = _data.Bathroom();
            ViewBag.twowheel = _data.twowheeler();
            ViewBag.fourwheel = _data.fourwheeler();
            ViewBag.dir = _data.Direction();
            ViewBag.floor = _data.Flooring();
            ViewBag.water = _data.WaterSupplies();
            ViewBag.furnish = _data.Furnishes();
            ViewBag.Amenities = new SelectList(db.Amenities, "AmenitiesId", "Amenitie");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Console.Write( ex.InnerException.StackTrace.ToString());
        }



        if (property == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(property);
    }`    

 <div class="form-box-left">
                   <h5>* Select The City :</h5>
                 @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, "Select City", new { @class = "text-box", Id = "City" })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)
                   <h5>* Locality :</h5>
```

Same code I'm using for the create page and its working there but not on the edit page . I  changed my code according to you but its still not submitting the data. While getting time it is ok.

Comment: Can we see the controller code for the edit and create action methods?

Answer (score 1):

Following code is the example of using empty DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityId", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select City", new { @class = "text-box", Id = "City" })
```

To Populate a DropDownList with relevant data you may send data using ViewBag.

Example:

First, you need to sore list of city into `ViewBag.City`.

```
ViewBag.City = new SelectList(cityList, value, text, selectedCity)
```

Then you can use `ViewBag.City` into DropDownList.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityId", ViewBag.City as SelectList, "Select City", new { @class = "text-box", Id = "City" })
```

Comment: This way it is not selecting the city for the edit page. It is not even selecting the list of cities as well .

Comment: I want a particular city to be selected besides populating it with the list of city.. This way I am able to get the list of cities only.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey, The selected value will be the value of the property `CityId` so if you set the value `CityId = 5` in your model and you have a `SlectListItem` with the value of 5, then it will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You passed null as elements for `Html.DropDownList`. In such case engine picks elements from ViewData dictionary under key of "CityId". I assume there is an object of type Int32 there (i.e. ViewData["CityId"]). That's the default behavior.

Comment: But ho wis it working for the create page then ?